# Make Visual Studio Code always show errors, even after closing the file that has errors?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Right now, in Visual Studio Code, errors shows up right in the file itself, in the "Problems" pane and in the file explorer, but **only when the file is opened**.

This is fine, but not ideal. As soon as I close the file, the error notification is gone... and probably, the site I'm committing my work too

Is there any setting to make the folder always red or marked, if any file in it shows errors? Otherwise, is there a command like "Inspect directory for errors"?

[image]

Comment: Related to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/44146)(?)